# Find capacitance such that voltage and current are in phase

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, passive-networks

I just cannot solve this exercice, any help?

[image]

This is what I have tried:

[image]

Comment: What would help you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Hint 1: Is \$\omega\$ given in the problem statement? If not, you can't answer the question. (At least, you can't get a numerical answer like "400 uF")

Hint 2: Consider what must be true about the load impedance for the supply voltage and current to be in phase.

Answer (score 1):

This is a homework problem so complete answers cannot be given unless the OP shows some work. Since you haven't shown anything, the best I can do is to give you a hint. If the voltage across and the current through a load are in phase, what does that say about the nature of the load: resistive, capacitive and/or inductive? Knowing that, find the impedance of the load in terms of C (the resistance and inductance are given). Now find what value of C will result in such a load.

Comment: I have just uploaded a photo of what I have tried

Answer (score 0):

Well, notice that we want to find:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{C}=\dots\tag1$$

We know that we can write:

$$\underline{\text{V}}_{\space\text{i}}=\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\cdot\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\tag2$$

So, we can see that:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\cdot\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\tag3$$

Using \$\arg\$ rules we know that we can write:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\cdot\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)+\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\tag4$$

So, we can rewrite \$(3)\$:

$$\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)+\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=\arg\left(\underline{\text{I}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\arg\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=0\tag5$$

We can now conclude that when the argument of the input impedance must be zero the imaginary of the input impedance must be zero. Using equations, we can write:

$$\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=0\tag6$$

We can see that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}&=\left(\frac{1}{\text{R}}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{C}}}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right)^{-1}\\
\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{\text{R}}+\text{j}\omega\text{C}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\right)^{-1}\\
\\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{R}}+\text{j}\omega\text{C}+\frac{1}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{R}}{\frac{\text{R}}{\text{R}}+\text{j}\omega\text{CR}+\frac{\text{R}}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}\text{j}\omega\text{CR}+\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}}{\text{j}\omega\text{L}}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}}{\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}}{\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}+\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\cdot\frac{\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}-\text{j}\omega\text{L}}{\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}-\text{j}\omega\text{L}}\\
\\
&=\frac{\text{j}\omega\text{LR}\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}-\text{j}\omega\text{L}\right)}{\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)\text{j}\omega\text{LR}-\text{j}\omega\text{L}\text{j}\omega\text{LR}}{\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\frac{\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)\text{j}\omega\text{LR}+\omega^2\text{L}^2\text{R}}{\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}
\end{split}\tag7
\end{equation}

So, we can see:

$$\Im\left(\underline{\text{Z}}_{\space\text{i}}\right)=\frac{\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)\omega\text{LR}}{\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)^2+\left(\omega\text{L}\right)^2}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\left(\text{R}-\omega^2\text{CLR}\right)\omega\text{LR}=0\tag8$$

Which implies:

$$\text{C}=\frac{\text{R}}{\omega^2\text{LR}}=\frac{1}{\omega^2\text{L}}\tag9$$

Answer (score -2):

In order for the current and voltage to be in phase $$\omega^{2}  = \frac{1}{{LC}} $$

because you have a parallel RLC circuit and the frequency at which the inductive reactance  = capacitive reactance is the **resonant** frequency

Comment: Do you know why?